# Android Studio: Horizontal Scroll View Freezes While Testing On Emulator

Tags: android, android-activity, android-emulator, horizontalscrollview

When I test my application (which has the Horizontal Scroll View) on my emulator, the scrolling part freezes in the middle. Sometimes the scroll freezes when I scroll the other way.The application doesn't freeze because the back button works. Will this freeze on an actual Android device, or is this just my emulator reacting?

Here is my scroll activity code:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="namee.com.myapp.School"
android:background="#000000">

<HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="20dp"
    android:background="#000000">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#000000">

       <ImageView android:src="@drawable/sunset3" android:layout_height="354dp" android:layout_width="600dp" />
       <ImageView android:src="@drawable/sunset3" android:layout_height="354dp" android:layout_width="600dp" />
       <ImageView android:src="@drawable/sunset3" android:layout_height="354dp" android:layout_width="600dp" />


       </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Here is sunset3

http://postimg.org/image/5l69hadel/

Comment: Just with the layout nobody can tell where's the problem. Post the java code or the stack trace (if there's one) too.

Comment: @Gumbo There is no .java, it's just in the activity.

Comment: @Gumbo Its really similar to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PAsR5sIi6E

Comment: So you are using just the java code generated by the `new Project` tool? Is there any error message/output in the `logcat`?

Comment: @Gumbo This code is in my activity.xml. There is nothing added in the .java.

Comment: Okay. Is there any Error in the `logcat`? If yes please post it.

Comment: @Gumbo Let me check..

Comment: @Gumbo Nothing bad appears.

Comment: Try my awnser. If that doesn't help i don't have any other idea what to do.

Comment: @Gumbo I already had this, check the update. Could you test it on your Android for me?

Comment: @Gumbo Do you think this will happen on an actual device?

Comment: I Can test it, but i don't have the `sunset3` drawable. I'll just use a random image.

Comment: @Gumbo look at the edit. I posted sunset3. Now can you try?

Comment: It runns perfectly on my Galaxy S4 mini (Android 4.4)

Comment: @Gumbo Thanks, that means its just the emulator

Comment: @Gumbo I want to give you a check, please edit your answer to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it on my Android device (Samsung Galaxy S4 mini, Android 4.4.2), and it's working fine. It might be some problem with the emulator ( e.g. memory limit too low).

Comment: What memory limit should I set it to?

Comment: @user3859020 As much as you can. Images are pretty big. If the emulator runs out of memory this should actually produce an error in the logcat, but you can try.

Comment: Won't that affect the compatibility for certain phones?

Comment: @user3859020 the memory limit for the emulator can be set below waht any phone has. But anyway, it might just be one of the normal performance issues in the emulator. It just is slow.

Comment: So if I increase my memory limit, will it not work on some phones?

Comment: @user3859020 It should run fine on all phones, but its an _emulator_ not a _simulator_ so it can have performance issues.

Comment: It wasn't memory size for me, but rather VM Heap Size, which explains why there was nothing in the logcat - it was a problem with the emulator. I increased the VM Heap Size to 256 and it stopped freezing.

Answer (score 3):

For me, turning off the "Use Host GPU" feature solved the freezing problem while scrolling in the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

In my case - vertical scrollbar - it was a matter of API number.
Same program running on 2 AVDs both using host GPU, RAM 512 and VM heap 32 (tried also 256).

API 21 works, API 19 freezes. Increasing the VM heap didn't solve the problem but I confirm that disabling the host GPU works (and obviously all gets really slower).